# CSS grid and semantic HTML

Tags: html, css, css-grid, semantic-markup

I'm learning CSS grid and while trying to do my layout and use semantic html at the same time I run into some problems

https://codepen.io/oscarryz/pen/oNNBKyd

So basically I'm doing  grid as 3x3 with empty space on the left and right and the content in the middle

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 40em 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    " . header . "
    " . content . "
    " . footer . ";
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}

.header, .content, .footer {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <header>
    <div class="header">header</div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="content">content</div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

As can be seen in the codepen above, this is not working. If I [remove the semantic tags it works](https://codepen.io/oscarryz/pen/abbpeLw), obviously there must be a correct way of doing this

Comment: `display: contents` is one way to go about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grid templates are for direct descendants.

The semantic elements should be referenced by tagname, not class:

```
/* changed from .header, which is a _child_ of header */
header {
  grid-area: header;
}

/* changed from .content, which is a _child_ of main */
main {
  grid-area: content;
}

/* changed from .footer, which is a _child_ of footer */
footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

Corrected codepen here: https://codepen.io/c_bergh/pen/eYYvOmG

Answer (score 2):

You've assigned grid areas to your non-semantic elements in your CSS. That's why the semantic elements are interfering with your grid — because they ended up not participating in your grid at all. If you had started out with the non-semantic structure, then migrated to semantic elements, this may have been a step you missed.

Assigning the grid areas to your semantic elements allows you to remove the non-semantic ones instead, completing this migration:

```css
html,
body,
.grid-container {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-container * {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 40em 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    " . header . "
    " . content . "
    " . footer . ";
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
}

main {
  grid-area: content;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <header>header</header>
  <main>content</main>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```